# Dramatiq doesn't add tasks to the queue

Tags: python, dramatiq

I'm trying to run some dramatiq actors from my Falcon API method, like this:

```
def on_post(self, req, resp):
    begin_id = int(req.params["begin_id"])
    count = int(req.params["count"])

    for page_id in range(begin_id, begin_id + count):
        process_vk_page.send(f"https://vk.com/id{page_id}")

    resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
```

My code gets to "send" method, goes through the loop without any problems. But where are no new tasks in the queue! Actor itself is not called, and "default" queue in my broker is empty. If I set custom queue, it is still empty. My actor looks like this:

```
@dramatiq.actor(broker=broker)
def process_vk_page(link: str):
   pass
```

Where broker is

```
broker = RabbitmqBroker(url="amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672")
```

RabbitMQ logs tell that it is connecting fine

I've done some additional research in debugger. It gets the message (which is meant to be sent to broker) fine, and *broker.enqueue* in Actor.send_with_options() returns no exceptions, although I can't really get it's internal logic. I don't really know why it fails, but it is definitely *RabbitmqBroker.enqueue()* which is causing the problem.

Broker is RabbitMQ 3.8.2 on Erlang 22.2.1, running in Docker from *rabbitmq* Docker Hub image with default settings. Dramatiq version is 1.7.0.

In RabbitMQ logs there are only connections to broker when app starts and disconnections when I turn it off, like this:

```
2020-01-05 08:25:35.622 [info] <0.594.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.594.0> (172.20.0.1:51242 -> 172.20.0.3:5672)
2020-01-05 08:25:35.627 [info] <0.594.0> connection <0.594.0> (172.20.0.1:51242 -> 172.20.0.3:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
2020-01-05 08:28:35.625 [error] <0.597.0> closing AMQP connection <0.597.0> (172.20.0.1:51246 -> 172.20.0.3:5672):
missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s
```

Broker is defined in `__init__.py` of main package and imported in subpackages. I'm not sure that specifying the same broker instance in decorators of all the functions is fine, but where are nothing in docs which bans it. I guess it doesn't matter, since if I create new broker for each Actor it still doesn't work.

I've tried to set Redis as broker, but I still get the same issue.

What might be the reason for this?

Comment: Any [filenotfounderror](https://dramatiq.io/troubleshooting.html#filenotfounderror-when-enqueueing) errors?

Comment: Hey could you provide some more information? Like the rabbitMQ logs, the versions of rabbitMQ, dramatiq & falcon you are using? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Luuk no exceptions at all

Answer (score 7):

Most likely the issue is that you're not telling the workers which broker to use, since you're not declaring a default broker.

You haven't mentioned how your files are laid out in your application, but, assuming your broker is defined as `broker` inside `tasks.py`, then you would have to let your workers know about it like so:

```
dramatiq tasks:broker
```

See the examples at the end of `dramatiq --help` for more information and patterns.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. Broker itself doesn't get any tasks in the first place, but even if it would, I'm already specifying the broker like ```dramatiq findface:broker &
```

Comment: How are you verifying that messages aren't being enqueued? Are you just using the logs or did you turn on the RMQ management plugin? IIRC, the logs don't show anything when messages are enqueued by default, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I'm using Pycharm JMS Messenger plugin for that

Comment: Try using RMQ's own management plugin to monitor your queues and disable the JMS Messenger plugin in case it's dequeueing messages itself (since it mentions it lets you browse messages, that's the only way it could on RMQ). Also, you can turn on verbose logging (`-vv`) to see exactly what the workers are doing.